# Can I put AdMob ads next to user generated content?

Tags: admob

Am I allowed to put Admob ads on a screen in an app with user generated content? This would only be what the individual user wrote on his/her own app, not what other people wrote. Something like this:

|-------------------------------------------------
|my notes,
|user types whatever here
|-------------------------------------------------
|admob
|-------------------------------------------------

Because the user can type anything they want, the text might include profanity, racial slurs, or 'click these ads' even though 99% of users will not put anything objectionable on there. Would this make it against AdMob rules? Is there a better way to monetize an app that is basically a notepad, where the user writes the content?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about AdMob policies, not programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Not against AdMob rules.

Some explanation: Nothing in the [AdMob Publisher Guidelines](http://helpcenter.admob.com/content/content-guidelines) says that this setup is against the rules.  Just make sure the ads aren't close to user controls in a way that may generate accidental clicks, and also to give your app the proper maturity rating if you turn on age appropriate ads.

I can't think of a better way to monetize the app unless you had some power features that were worth paying for.  Here's a suggestion though - since the keyboard covers the bottom of the bottom of the screen, maybe you'd want the ad on the top of the notepad so that the ad isn't blocked by the keyboard.