# Admob ads between content in Android WebView

Tags: android, cordova, admob

I would like to implement multiple Admob in a generated webview page that can be scrolled.

There should be a list like this one where the Ad is appearing once in a while between the other items

```
  ITEM1
  ITEM2
    AD 1
  ITEM 3
  ITEM 4
    AD 2
```

It seems from the other [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781617/can-i-put-admob-ads-next-to-user-generated-content) that this is allowed in the TOS of admob. But how to implement that ? Any suggestion that can be useful ?

[Actually I am trying to implement this in Cordova/Phonegap but at least it should first be possible with the standard Android Webview]

Comment: As a side note: beware that you can only have 1 ad visible at the same time (also I'm not sure about having more than 2 ads on a single activity).

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend against this. You will burn countless hours trying and probably failing to get this to work. You are far better off providing a static AdView atthe top or bottom of the screen and have y

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I wonder what "reddit is fun" app for Android is doing. They are able to display multiple ads after a certain number of items [see http://goo.gl/JrAX5U ] . Are they using something different then ?

Comment: Who knows, but I bet they spent many hours getting it to work and probably still get lots of crashes and pissed off users.